# Browser stops working for a while after synchronous ajax call in a for loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser

This is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: "/MyController/MyMethod",
        success: function (data) {
            if (i == 0) {
                $('#result_progress').hide();
                $('#result_msg').hide();
                $('#details').show();
            } else if (i == 1) {
                $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                async: true,
                url: "/Import/Finish",
                success: function (data) {
                        ....                        
                });                                            
            }
            if (i < 2) {
                $('#details').html($('#details').html() + 'someText'));
            }                                        
        }
    });
}
```

In this example the iteration is small, but I made the method simpler here. I know that I can use switch, but that's not the point. In reality it is with much bigger number of loops. Nevermind that, the error happens for this code too.

Here's what happens:
if I put breakpoint in the success part of the first ajax call and when I debug in Chrome, eveything works fine.
Here's what I mean by working fine: after the method goes in the first success, I want some divs to be hidden and  the message I get as a result from the ajax call to be shown. The second time the first success is entered, another string will be ADDED to the previous.
In the end, when the second success part is entered, that message is hidden and I'm showing some data.

And this is what happens:
everything is fine until MyMethod is called. When it gets called, the browser stops working. If I press my left mouse key, nothing happens. When MyMethod is called for the last time, the browser works fine, I get quick glimpse of the message and then it shows the data from the second ajax call. And the message that I see shortly is the whole message, from all the calls to MyMethod, which shouldn't happen.

I want it to be shown for the entire for loop and before the Finish method. And it shouldn't be the same message. It should get bigger with every ajax call to MyMethod.

Comment: Why are you using an sync call in the first place?

Comment: What did you expect the browser to do with synchronous ajax calls in for loop? It is the same as with alert, in order to continue script execution browser has to wait for the ajax call to finish first.

Comment: @Chad Because the ajax call is in a for loop.

Comment: @petko_stankoski I'm asking why, there is no reason for that. You can use asynchronous controls to run them simultaneously or in series. You don't need a for loop with synchronous calls.

Comment: @Chad How would I do that without for loop? For example, if the loop doesn't go to 2, it goes to 200.

Comment: @Corneliu Ok. I have two calls to MyMethod. I undertsand the browser waits for every ajax call. So it waits for the first one, then the second one. But after the first one, it should write the message.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve here. Could you give more info on that.

Comment: @Corneliu How would I call the ajax in the for loop, without using async: false ?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786621/preferred-technique-for-pacing-http-requests-in-js-jquery

Comment: The reason I've asked for more details is that it looks like you're trying to show progress feedback on a long running task. There are different techniques to achieve that. Long polling, recursive Ajax etc.

Comment: @Corneliu Yes, that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a "recursive" function to help you control flow with asynchronous calls. Instead of running them synchronously, you can run them all asynchronously and then call the function again when it is time for the next one.

Something like:

```
function doCall(i) {
    if(i > howManyToRun) return;

    $.ajax({
        //...
        succcess: function(data) {
            //...
            //time to start the next one
            doCall(++i);
        },
        error: function() {
            //call the next one on error?
            doCallI(++i);
        }
    })
}
```

This way they run async, don't block everything while they are calling; but still run in series.